# In what order are jquery events called?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using this HTML:

`<a href="#" class="topHierarchy big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" >`

Both "topHierarchy" and "big-link" are used to add jquery event handlers (onClick).

`big-link` is used to show a popup box. Whereas `tophierarchy` for puting data in a div in the popup.

But when I click on that link the pop up comes first and then data changes into div.

So is there a way to order the events that are triggered by jQuery? At first the `tophiearchy` event should be triggered and then `big-link`.

Comment: AFAIK, the event handlers will be called in the order in which they are registered

Comment: i thought so but dis is not happening...

Comment: add callback function. Can you post you code??

Comment: check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ruu9j/)

Comment: sorry i am not getting...

Comment: You are fighting a losing battle if you are trying to get your event handlers to fire in a specific order.  That is not how event-based programming works.  I encourage you to reconsider your approach and instead enforce the order of your actions within a single event handler.  Perhaps your event handler can check the css classes on the target and take actions based on that.

Comment: @Brandon then what should i do..?

Comment: I've mentioned one way (in your event handler, use something like `if ($(ev.currentTarget).hasClass('big-link')) { ... }`.  If you want a more complete answer, start a new question and post some of your JavaScript code and ask for a better way to accomplish your goal of running your actions in the desired order instead of trying to get your event handlers registered in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I think in jQuery "Callbacks are executed in the order they were added".

May be you can try something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="big-link topHierarchy" data-reveal-id="myModal" >
```

Also can you post your JS code here to see how and in what order have you defined your corresponding methods.